# Why do reference data types point?

Tags: java, pointers, types, reference, reference-type

Consider:

[image]

I understand that for primitive data types, the memory allocated (orange rectangle) contains the thing you want, but for reference data types, the memory allocated contains a reference/pointer to the thing that you want.

Why design it like this? For things that are usually reference data types (Objects, Arrays etc.), why not just put the thing you want in the orange rectangle?

Comment: If the thing was stored inside the orange rectangle and not a pointer to it, then it would be impossible to share the same orange rectangle across multiple objects.  Only copies could be past about.

Comment: It's certainly a design option (C++ does it for values on the stack), but it was not one taken by Java. One can argue whether or not that is the best choice, but that's the way they went for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How big is that orange rectangle going to be?

For primitives, you already know the size already. But what about for objects? For concrete final classes, you'd know how much memory is going to be used already... but what about other cases?

For example:

```
InputStream x = new FileInputStream("foo");
```

If the variable `x` has to contain *all* the fields of the object (and know what type it is) the it's got to be big enough for all the `FileInputStream` fields. Okay, in this case we can manage that, although it's slightly odd for the size of an `InputStream` variable to be defined by its usage. What about this:

```
InputStream x = getInputStream("foo");
```

The compiler can't know what type of object would be returned by `getInputStream` - so how can it know how big `x` is going to be? When the value of `x` is a reference, it's much simpler - it's the same size regardless of the actual type of the object it refers to.

Then of course you want to be able to share objects between various "users" of that object, which is where using references becomes very efficient. (We don't have to copy all the fields every time we pass a value around - we just copy the reference.) Treating objects as values instead of references changes the semantics a lot. For example:

```
// A simple mutable type with get/setValue doing the obvious thing
MutableType x = new MutableType();
x.setValue(5);
MutableType y = x;
x.setValue(10);
System.out.println(y.getValue());
```

With references, this prints 10 because `x` and `y` are just references to the same object. With value type semantics, presumably it would print 5 instead. Not unreasonable - but a very big change in how the language works.

Then there are other issues besides, but I think that's enough to start with :)

Of course, C++ has answers to all of these things, but the designers of Java deemed it simpler to just use references for all non-primitive types.

Comment: This is spot on, because it hints at one of the most important aspects of OOP, which is type substitution.

Comment: The `InputStream` example makes sense, but don't you usually know how much space to allocate for an object? Like if I do `String name`, doesn't it know how much space to allocate because the type is `String`?

Comment: Could you elaborate on when you'd want to share an object? I have a vague idea, but I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @AdamZerner String is a perfect example. How much space do you allocate for it? 10 characters? 100? 1000?

Comment: @AdamZerner: That's why I said it would be feasible for concrete final classes - but that's only a fairly small proportion of variables, in my experience. Making the language treat everything consistently leads to a much cleaner design.

Comment: @Durandal: You allocate enough space for a `char[]` and a length/index/whatever. Unlike .NET, the String class in Java is still a normal class in terms of each object being the same size.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'd like to skip the detail that there's a char[] inside the string, the problem is the same (only that its really the char[] having the problem), but if you like to have no references, that char[] would need to be *embedded* into the string anyway.

Comment: @Durandal: That's a "detail" that destroys your point though. `String` *is* a perfectly good example of where we could copy the fields... arrays are a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're missing the point, see my edit of previous comment. Without pointers everything would need to be embedded, you end up with a giant structure that includes structures and so on.

Comment: @Durandal: But the OP was giving `String` as an example where it would be okay - not saying that references would be banned completely. A proposal of "embed values directly for fields of concrete final types" is a reasonable one to discuss, and that's how I interpreted the OP's comment.

Comment: @JonSkeet It would be okay *only* because java guarantees immutability for String. Change String to StringBuilder and the argument goes out of the window.

Comment: @Durandal: Only if you want sharing. We'd be changing the language significantly, certainly - but I think it's entirely reasonable for the OP to ask about that... and I don't think taking the OP's question about `String` and trying to twist it around to cover *everything* is helpful. At this point, I think it would be better if you wrote your own answer. (I've edited a bit about mutability into my answer.)

Answer (score 3):

If we were to store the object directly in the memory box, then it would be impossible to have multiple references point to the same object. This is problematic if I want to do something like pass it as an argument to a method. That creates a new reference to the object, and passes it in, allowing the method to operate on it. If the object was actually in the memory box, it would have to pass in a copy, which a) would eat more memory space than needed, and b) would mean that changes made in the function would not effect the original object, merely the copy.

For instance, the below code would not work if the object were actually in the memory box, instead of a reference.

```
public class blah{
    private ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

    // if the object resided directly in memory, this method would do nothing of use
    // as it would only make changes to the copy it was passed, rather than the original.
    public void add Value(ArrayList<String> array, String value){
        array.add(value);
    }

}
```